# How to set a certain radio button to checked "true"

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have web form markup as follows:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[1]" class="optionA">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[1]" class="optionB">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[1]" class="optionC">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[2]" class="optionA"><!--want to check this one-->
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[2]" class="optionB">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[2]" class="optionC">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[3]" class="optionA">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[3]" class="optionB">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fieldSelection[3]" class="optionC">
```

How can I set only one of the boxes to checked -- example, check button `optionA` for `fieldSelection[2]`?

Here is what I have, but obviously it checkes all 3 buttons:

```
$('.optionA').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: I'm guessing that there's probably close to a dozen ways to do this.

Comment: The way that you're determining which one should be checked will most likely influence the best way to check that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):**

```
$('input.optionA[name="fieldSelection[2]"]').prop('checked', true);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgRE7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function setChecked(string fieldSelection, string className)
   {
      if ( $.trim($(this).attr('name')) == $.trim(fieldSelection) )
       {
        $("." + className ).prop('checked', true);
       }
    }
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok, thanks @NickProzee. [at]billyonecan provided an answer already that I tested and implemented successfully.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Although with this method you can also switch classes